# How can I keep repeating several commands until they all succeed?

Tags: bash, shell, psql

I have a sequence of `psql` commands in a `.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
psql -U postgres -1 -f file1.sql
psql -U postgres -1 -f file2.sql
psql -U postgres -1 -f file3.sql
psql -U postgres -1 -f file4.sql
psql -U postgres -1 -f file5.sql
```

I want to keep repeating these `psql` commands in block until they all succeed. So if for example the command for `file4.sql` fails, we should restart with `file1.sql`.

Should I do such logic in the `.sql` file or in the shell script?

Comment: I would do this in a shell script. Is a fail returning a good exit code (different from zero?)

Comment: @kvantour From what I have tested, a non-zero is returned on failure.

Comment: Have a look at @JohnZwinck 's answer. This is why I informed about the return code.

Comment: You *probably* want to do this with one call to `psql`, so that the entire suite can be executed within one transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while ! (psql -U postgres -f file1.sql
      && psql -U postgres -f file2.sql
      && psql -U postgres -f file3.sql
      && psql -U postgres -f file4.sql
      && psql -U postgres -f file5.sql)
do
    echo retrying...
done
```

Comment: The nice part about this is that it will not attempt `file5.sql` if `file4.sql` fails.

Comment: This works! I did not know this would fail fast, meaning that `file3`, `file4` and `file5` will not be executed if `file2` fails.

Comment: Thank you kindly.

Comment: bash actually has an `until` loop, so `until a && b && ...; do echo retrying; done`